# Authors are placed vertically instead of horizontally despite the usage of \and, how to fix it?

Tags: titles

I am writing an article using Overleaf but my authors are getting placed vertically instead of horizontally. I am pasting here my preamble and the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{cl}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cl}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{\tablename\ #2}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=myformat,labelsep=period}  
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\thetable\alph{subtable}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subtable{}
\makeatletter

\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} 

\lstset{
  aboveskip=1ex,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!25},
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  belowskip=1ex,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=fullflexible,
  framerule=0pt,
  framexrightmargin=0em,
  framexleftmargin=0em,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
  tabsize=2,
  showlines=true
}

\usepackage{lstbayes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}


\title{\textbf{Title title title}}

\author{Author A\\ \small Affiliation A
        \and 
        Author B\\ \small Affiliation B 
        \and 
        Author C\\ \small Affiliation C}

\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

And here is what I'm getting:

[image]

What should I do to fix it? I thought that if I use `\and`, I should get the authors placed horizontally? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Please trim your example down so that it only contains the code that shows the problem (which in this case probably means remove all the packages except for `authblk`).

Comment: why load `graphicx` three times?

Comment: @AlanMunn What if one of these packages is causing the problem? That is why I pasted them all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I didn't even notice that. The reason would be because I just know very basic Latex stuff and I've been copy pasting whatever the code appeared in some of the solutions I was looking for

Comment: @J.Doe it is easy for you to test that before posting, simply remove every package you can remove while still showing the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In that case there will probably be no need for a post at all. I just thought someone might already know that "Oh, this commonly happens when X is loaded together with Y. I see you have loaded them both, so there's your problem"

Comment: you have threeparttable and caption duplicated as well. Copying preambles is a cause for common errors, always start from an empty preamble and just add packages if you need them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. As said previously, this preamble was formed by me just copy pasting stuff from this site whenever I encountered some problem in the actual body of the text I was formatting. Someone would post a solution and also the packages required for that solution, and then I would just dump them into the preamble. I did start with an empty preamble 2 years ago, and then I did what I just described above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're loading the package `authblk` which redefines how the title is written, but it seems that you're looking for the default behavior. Just commenting out the line

```
\usepackage{authblk}
```

from your code yields the expected output

[image]

It would probably be a good idea to try and understand what's in your preamble. As pointed out by others in the comments, you load several packages (at least `graphicx` and `threeparttable`) multiple times, which is certainly not needed. Taking the time to understand what each line is for might save you some trouble later.

Answer (score 4):

The following example is a minimal version of the OP's problem, in the sense that it replicates the formatting problem *without* any of the fluff:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title title title}
\author{Author A\\ \small Affiliation A
        \and 
        Author B\\ \small Affiliation B 
        \and 
        Author C\\ \small Affiliation C}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It's not clear to me why the OP loads the [authblk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package.

The OP may want to either simply not load this package at all or start using its syntax model to adjust the way the author block gets typeset. For instance:

[image]

Note that I wouldn't use `\textbf` (or, for that matter, `\bfseries`) in the argument of `\title`. The facts that (a) the title's font size is quite large and (b) the title is separated vertically from any other stuff (such as the author block...) suffice to draw attention to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\small}
%\renewcommand\Authands{ and } % if "Oxford comma" is not desired

\title{Title title title}
\author[1]{Author A} \affil[1]{Affiliation A}
\author[2]{Author B} \affil[2]{Affiliation B}
\author[3]{Author C} \affil[3]{Affiliation C}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you also for expanding the code. Here is the reason why the `authblk` package was there. The document that I am working on has been a work in progress for two years. I now remember that I wanted to format my title in a specific way back then and thus I included this package. However, now we need to make the title compliant with the formatting of the journal, hence why I need to change it. I have little knowledge of these packages and I wouldn't have remembered that the `authblk` package is the one responsible for titles if someone hadn't pointed it out

Comment: Also per the formatting guidelines of the journal, the title needs to be bold, so that is why `\textbf{}` is used.

Comment: @J.Doe - You're welcome. :-) About the issue of loading packages at one point and later not remembering why they're being loaded: In my own working papers, I find it useful -- extremely useful, in fact -- to (a) only load one package per `\usepackage` directive and (b) always provide a short comment what's being achieved by loading this package. It's also a good way to avoid loading packages either more than once or, worse, with conflicting options.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely keep that in mind! In the next paper I will definitely include comments, so that I can know exactly which packages do I need for which specific issue in the text